# Market Discrepancy in ETFs

Tags: etf

Today Yahoo, Google, CNBC, etc. are all reporting an open for DDM of \$106.95,  a close of \$107.69 and a delta on the day of \$2.69. But the arithmetic difference between the open and the close is actually \$0.74. Why is there such a huge discrepancy?

Answer (score 2):

The day's net change is typically displayed as the $Close$ to $Close$ difference. So today's close of $\$107.69$, yesterday's close is $\$105.00$. So the net change, $\$107.69 - \$105.00 = \$2.69$. If you were to calculate $Open$ to $Close$, you'd get what you expect, $\$0.74$.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it resolves your question.